# How to add a user to app in portal.azure's enterprise applications?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

In Azure Portal in my Azure Active Directory in Enterprise Aplications I have an app. Is it possible to add someone to the users group via Microsopht.Graph to this app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're after the Add Member option

> Use this API to add a member to an Office 365 Group, a security group, or a mail-enabled security group through the members navigation property.
>
> You can add users or other groups. Important: You can add only users to Office 365 Groups.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript

Comment: So I need to create some group and add my application to it? Or it is in some group by default?

Comment: You should have some groups already you can see the groups by calling 

> GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$orderby=displayName

Comment: There is 100 of groups, so probably more they just don't load. How can I know which covers my app? And how to display all? I do it like the SDK example from the bottom of the page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs

Comment: you can page through the results by calling https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$orderby=displayName&$top=900 that will list 900 groups to get the next batch call the @odata.nextLink from the response

Comment: How can I do this using SDK? 
     var groups = await graphClient.Groups
                        .Request()
                        .Top(999)
                        .GetAsync();

Comment: I don't use c# but it looks like it from some of the issues listed https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=paging

Comment: Even if I can see all groups how can I know in which my app exists?